# In Crystal Reports, can I combine the detail lines of the main report with the detail lines of a subreport?

Tags: crystal-reports

This is a resource planning report, and the goal is to have a running total of usage and purchases for each component.  Currently, I have the main report details section that lists usage amounts ordered by date for a part.  In the group footer, I have a subreport that lists all of the purchase orders for the part.  I want the detail lines of the purchases subreport to be included among the detail lines of the main report at the appropriate date, kind of like a list of credits and debits. Then, for each line, the running total will subtract usage amounts and add purchase amounts.  I put the subreport in the main report details section, but then it is run for each line.  So I tried to suppress duplicates, but it doesn't land in the correct date position.  I tried various other things like splitting the detail section of the main report and changing the linked fields of the reports to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight.  You have a table of "credits" and another table of "debits" and you want them both to appear in an orderly manner in the details section.  You tried a few different methods (those were all good attempts, by the way), but didn't get what you liked.

I recommend looking at your data source and seeing if you can union the two datasets there.  In other words, don't bother with doing all that in Crystal.